How to implement different access levels for different users in Azure
I have a web application, which has a button which leads to another page but that page can be accessed only by certain users but not all the end users. Given that I have already implemented authentication but the problem is that how to give access to only certain users. Then how can we implement this functionality? Since I am new to Azure any kind of help/leads could be really helpful.

How have you implemented authentication? Are you using Azure AD? Please edit your question and include the details.

Yes, I did but I don't know how to restrict users from using it. For now the users just have to login and then everyone are able to use the admin page. But that should not be the case, only the certain people whom I want to give access only they should have the access to that. How shall I implement that change?

Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78136510/is-there-a-way-to-manage-users-from-web-app-when-users-are-maintained-in-azure-a.

Do let me know if this does not help and I will reopen the question.
